# netplan: is there an equivalent to `post-up`?

Tags: networking, dhcp, netplan

I have a VM with one interface configured via DHCP and the other configured statically. It boots up and configures the interfaces on start-up. However, in this VM I need a static route configured to the default router of the DHCP network (which I know is 192.168.0.1) because the gateway goes through the statically configured interface. So I included:

```
routes:
   - to: 172.16.0.0/16
     via: 192.168.0.1
     metric: 10
```

at the end of the DHCP configuration, but I need to configure this route manually in order to have the right routing configuration.

This worked with `ifupdown` with this simple configuration:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    post-up ip route add 172.16.0.0/16 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 metric 10
```

So it doesn't seem to be rocket science...

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible to do in netplan yaml using routes as you tried to do, but it doesn't work because of https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1781652.

As a workaround, you should be able to do this using a hook in .  See the networkd-dispatcher(8) manpage for details.